# Sum revenue by unique customer and month and product

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I am trying to sum revenue for unique clients within the month by product.

Table below represents the raw data that i have.

| Report_Month | cl_Code | Revenue | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31/08/2023 | ALT122 | 40 | DD |
| 31/08/2023 | ATT047 | 50 | DD |
| 31/07/2023 | BAP022 | 40 | DD |
| 31/07/2023 | BAP022 | 25 | AA |
| 31/08/2023 | BAP022 | 124.8 | DD |
| 31/08/2023 | BAP022 | 25 | AA |
| 31/08/2023 | BLE049 | 85 | DD |
| 31/07/2023 | CEN204 | 40 | DD |
| 31/08/2023 | CEN204 | 42.1 | DD |
| 31/08/2023 | CHI256 | 181.2 | DD |
| 31/08/2023 | FAR140 | 100 | DD |
| 31/07/2023 | GOO142 | 140 | DD |
| 31/08/2023 | GOO142 | 140 | DD |
| 31/08/2023 | GRE596 | 80 | DD |
| 31/08/2023 | GRE596 | 250 | AA |
| 31/07/2023 | INT485 | 85 | DD |
| 31/07/2023 | INT485 | 25 | AA |
| 31/08/2023 | INT485 | 25 | AA |
| 31/08/2023 | INT485 | 85 | DD |
| 31/08/2023 | JJA004 | 50 | DD |
| 31/07/2023 | LAN308 | 101 | DD |
| 31/08/2023 | LAN308 | 82.86 | DD |
| 31/08/2023 | LIF104 | 113.8 | DD |
| 31/07/2023 | NEW492 | 85.6 | DD |
| 31/08/2023 | NEW492 | 85.9 | DD |
| 31/07/2023 | ORA061 | 85 | DD |
| 31/08/2023 | ORA061 | 89 | DD |
| 31/07/2023 | POL137 | 65 | DD |
| 31/08/2023 | POL137 | 65 | DD |
| 31/07/2023 | PRO581 | 40 | DD |
| 31/07/2023 | PRO581 | 25 | AA |
| 31/08/2023 | PRO581 | 25 | AA |
| 31/08/2023 | PRO581 | 49 | DD |
| 31/07/2023 | RCA003 | 250 | DD |
| 31/08/2023 | RCA003 | 250 | DD |
| 31/08/2023 | REG109 | 40 | DD |
| 31/07/2023 | RIV132 | 85.5 | DD |
| 31/08/2023 | RIV132 | 118 | DD |
| 31/07/2023 | VIV046 | 25 | AA |
| 31/07/2023 | VIV046 | 41.72 | DD |
| 31/07/2023 | VIV046 | 25 | AA |
| 31/07/2023 | VIV046 | 41.72 | DD |
| 31/08/2023 | VIV046 | 122.94 | DD |
| 31/08/2023 | VIV046 | 122.94 | DD |
| 31/08/2023 | YOU274 | 162.18 | DD |

The results that i am expecting is in the table below.

|  | Jul-23 | Aug-23 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 100 | 325 |  |
| DD | 1058.82 | 2156.78 |  |

impacted lines 41 ,43 , 44 , 45

If you look at raw data table, you will see that customer code 123 appears in Jul-23 twice for the same product DD but i only want to include in my sum for the month once. in my real-world data, there would not be a situation where the is a different revenue amount for the same customer and product. E.g. customer code would not have product DD have revenue in the same month with one row 150 and another 100 they will always be the same value.

I have tried the following formula.

```
=SUM(UNIQUE(FILTER(REVENUE,(REPORT_MONTH=C2),TRUE,TRUE)))
```

Any help would be really appreciated!!

Comment: Same question as before: what should be the result if the revenue in row 2 is e.g. 150 - still same month, same customer, same product as in row 1?

Comment: @Ike it should ignore it. In my real world scenario there wouldnt be a situation where the customer has a different revenue value for a the same month for the same product (just the way my data is structured)

Comment: If I am not wrong, in the month of `AUG` `AA` should be showing `200` instead of `100`, is that correct?

Comment: In real world data, in any situation, a customer or a product cant have two different revenues unless its an human error. well, there can be duplicates which is still an human error.

Comment: Wouldn't a Pivot Table work for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the one or the other following formulas which uses <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper functions viz. <kbd>MAKEARRAY( )</kbd> or <kbd>REDUCE( )</kbd> with <kbd>MAP( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,UNIQUE(A2:D8),
     b, INDEX(a,,1),
     c, INDEX(a,,3),
     d, INDEX(a,,4),
     ub, TOROW(UNIQUE(b)),
     ud, SORT(UNIQUE(d)),
     VSTACK(HSTACK("Product",ub),
     HSTACK(ud,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(ud),COLUMNS(ub),
            LAMBDA(x,y,SUM((b=INDEX(ub,y))*(d=INDEX(ud,x))*c))))))
```

---

Or, [image]

---

```
=LET(
     a,UNIQUE(A2:D8),
     b, INDEX(a,,1),
     c, INDEX(a,,3),
     d, INDEX(a,,4),
     ub, TOROW(UNIQUE(b)),
     ud, SORT(UNIQUE(d)),
     REDUCE(HSTACK("Product",ub),ud,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,
            HSTACK(y,MAP(ub,LAMBDA(m,SUM((y=d)*(m=b)*c))))))))
```

---

Same formula works with the required output.

[image]

---

[image]

---

You can download the workbook from **[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cj0gFaj_W_T1lZ6G6?e=flJ9e3)**

---

Comment: @Mauykh Bhattacharya  this works on the example data i provided but when i apply it to the real data set, its still including the value for duplicated customer account with the same product. My real world data is set out exactly the same as the example data but just a larger data set so not sure why its not looking at the customer code and says oh this is a duplicate based on product month and customer id

Comment: Can you show me your excel, if there is no issue, at least few rows of data. So I can see, but this should work. You can share a `onedrive` link in the comments below

Comment: @Mauykh Bhattacharya  updated the table in the main question with the larger dataset. if you maintain the table order the lines impact 41, 43 44 45

Comment: @Fazza have you posted the output as well

Comment: @Fazza so for `AA` for the month of `Jul` it will be 100 and month of `Aug` it will be 325 where as for `DD` it will be 1058.82 and 2156.78 is that correct?

Comment: updated expected result table. But yes correct

Comment: @Fazza the formula still gives me correct output as shown. let me post a workbook link as well

Comment: @Fazza you can download the workbook from **[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cj0gFaj_W_T1lZ6G6?e=flJ9e3)**

Comment: It worked. Found what i was doing wrong. I was referring to table name in the first UNIQUE which was causing the error as it contained the header as well. Once i changed to cell references instead worked straight away

Comment: @Fazza cool, glad to know it worked finally for you =)